# $exists in python

Tags: python, list, mongodb

I am iterating through a database and want to add the variable value of key "number" to a list x, only if this key exists. There are some documents where there is no key "number".

Inside mongo I would use the $exist, but I don't know how to do it in python. I tried this but it doesn't work...

```
for i in database:
    try:
        x.append(i["number"])
    except NameError:
        break
```

This doesn't work, and I am sure there is a more elegant way...

Comment: `i.has_key('number')` check should do it

Comment: @avasal `'key' in obj` is the preferred method, and `.has_key` has gone the way of the dodo in 3.x

Comment: This is a EAFP vs. LBYL decision - in Python, you usually try something and catch an exception...

Comment: @Julia You already heard about the quality of a statement like  "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` operator is the canonical way to test existence of a key in a container:

```
for i in database:
    if "number" in i:
        x.append(i["number"])
```

Comment: No, it works just fine and [is documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict); try it. In fact, `"number" in i.keys()` is wrong because it forces a linear scan over dict keys, while `"number" in i` performs an O(1) lookup.

Comment: @juankysmith Be careful about claims taht something is wrong. Better check it beforehand...

Comment: @glglgl Playing devil's advocate - if using Python 3.x, then `.keys()` is a set like object and not a list, so `'number' in d.keys()` won't perform a linear scan, but it's definitely nowhere near good practice

Answer (score 2):

Are you effectively writing - the try/append/except is making it a bit confusing...

```
x = [i['number'] for i in database if 'number' in i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close to what you want: a non-existing key gives no `NameError`, but a `KeyError`.

So

```
for i in database:
    try:
        x.append(i["number"])
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual code is near to what you want. You only have to use the `continue` instead of `break` in the except clause. Like so

```
for i in database:
    try:
        x.append(i["number"])
    except NameError:
        continue
```

Comment: If there's nothing else in the loop, `pass` will work just as well.